# Is it possible to get a file without knowing file hash

Tags: p2p, ipfs

I read some articles about how to protect files with encryption on the ipfs network. If i understand ipfs correctly, without knowing file hash you can not get file on ipfs network(maybe i am wrong).

**My question**

Is it possible to get a file without knowing file hash? If not why we need to encrypt files on the network(i assume that file hash is known by only file owner)?

Comment: I think since data exist on your disk (non-encrypted) you can  make it lisible. (something like disk dump)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not encrypt the data, then whoever is in control of the IPFS node can very easily just look at the data. If you want to be reasonably sure that only the appropriate people can view a piece of data, you need to encrypt it in some way.